# Single queries or JOINs on MySQL (plus Redis) implementation for Hexagonal Architecture

Tags: mysql, redis, sequelize.js, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture

I’m developing a NodeJS project with hexagonal architecture but I have a big doubt about how to manage the workflow in implementations of databases (MySQL & Redis)

#### MySQL implementation:

- I’m using **Sequelize ORM** & it’s possible to populate models to get associations (**JOINs**). Sequelize implementation let me to set up some options in one model to include other model directly in its **own repository**. I don’t need to have a dependency from the second model.

#### Redis implementation:

- However, with Redis, I need to query all resources **separately**. This is normal. It’s not possible to associate models & I have to go to **repository of second model**. These actions should be done in the use case I supposed.

Example:

MySQL implementation sequence

> 1.1. GetContentsWithVideosUseCase -> I create a Criteria for get all Contents joining its own Videos
>
> 1.2. ContentRepository.findAll(criteriaForJoinVideos) -> Here I already have each content with its videos.
>
> 1.3. GetContentsWithVideosUseCase -> I doesn't need anymore so return it to controller.

Redis implementation sequence

> 2.1. GetContentsWithVideosUseCase -> I create a Criteria for get all Contents.
>
> 2.2. ContentRepository.findAll(criteriaContents) -> Here I only have each content.
>
> 2.3. GetContentsWithVideosUseCase -> I have contents but now I need videos from them. Contents.map & create criteria for each query of videos by content.
>
> 2.4. VideoRepository.findAll(criteriaVideosByContent) -> Here I already have videos for one content.
>
> 2.5. GetContentsWithVideosUseCase -> I have now all videos for all contents & I compose the object which will be returned.

#### Question!

We can see that the problem here is that usecase should be different depend of implementation & that shouldn’t happen.

The question with this scenario what is the best & most correct practice:

- Should I do all the MySQL queries independently (separating them on respective reporsitories) & leaving JOINs?
- Is it possible to keep JOINs with Redis implementation?
- Have you dealt with this ever?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Redis should be compacted into one step. In its repository should be made all queries needed to retrieve content with its videos and returns it to your domain services.
Hexagonal architecture assumes that your db is a detail, so your domain services doesn't care about does db support relations or not. You don't care how many queries are made inside, until performance is low, but it is other story.

Important note is that repository should be rather per AggregateRoot nor per Entity.